# Excel VBA - Copying a cell within an array and pasting to next empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA and trying to write a macro that will copy a reference number (column A) of an entry if column Y contains certain text (CHK). I have been able to set up an array that will check if a cell contains the value CHK and copies the reference number if it does (with this then repeating for each cell).

What i am struggling with is pasting the values for each cell into the next empty cell in row A of another workbook. I have managed to copy the value into the next empty cell but I am unsure how to then move one cell down for the next run through of the array. Whereas, at the moment the value in the cell is overridden each time the array runs

My current code is shown below:

```
Sub Copy_detailed_WithNum_V2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set ws1 = Sheets("Detailed Register-All")
Set ws2 = Sheets("VIPP Register")
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Activate Detailed Reigster sheet
ws1.Activate

Set SrchRng = Range("Y:Y")


For Each cel In SrchRng

    'Check if the cell contains CHK text
    If InStr(1, cel.Text, "CHK") Then
    'Copy rerference number if entry has CHK value
    cel.Offset(0, -24).Copy
    'Activate VIPP Register sheet
    ws2.Activate
    'Paste in the next empty cell in Coulmn A
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End If

'Check next cell
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: You are not qualifying your instances of `Cells` and `Range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely due to your instances of `Range` and `Cells` not being qualified with a worksheet. Also, notice that you do not need to `Activate` a worksheet in order to modify it.

Instead of copying values, you can just set the value of 2 ranges equal to each other which is what I have done here.

Laslty, your search range is currently set to `Y:Y` which is the entire column (a little over 1 million cells to check). You need to minimize this to a minimal/necessary range. I have this set to start in `Y2` (assuming you have a header) and scan down to the last used cell in column `Y`

---

```
Sub Copy_detailed_WithNum_V2()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("Detailed Register-All")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("VIPP Register")
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range, lastRow As Long

Set SrchRng = ws1.Range("Y2:Y" & ws1.Range("Y" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If InStr(1, cel.Text, "CHK") Then
            lastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            ws2.Cells(lastRow, 1).Value = cel.Offset(0, -24).Value
        End If
    Next cel
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I totally misread this question somehow. Saw other issues and completely ignored the main one. Time to log off for the night lol @bigben

Comment: Thanks for that worked well. 

I had another query in regards to copying over new records that have been added to my sheet. When i run the macro it will copy over all records that fit the criteria, which then means i'll be duplicating records that have already been copied. Is there a way to only copy new records that meet the criteria

Comment: Yes that is possible but it is out of the scope of your initial question. If questions were allowed to continuously evolve, they would never truly be solved. If this solution answered your original question, you should mark it as solved (check mark to left). If you need more work, you should research it and make a honest attempt to solve it. If you need help along the way, the question deserves its own post to help both you and future readers with similar issues.

Comment: Make sense thanks for the help urdearboy. I'll do some more research.